# Как сделать чтобы данные layout менялись при нажатии на button/imageView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity, android-layout

Как сделать чтобы данные layout менялись(текст, картинки) при нажатии на button/imageView?
Для каждого персонажа нужно много layout,activity нужно как-то минимизировать код...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agillity);
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        imageAntimag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAntimag);
        imageAntimag.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHeroes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageAntimag:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityHero.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

герой

```
public class ActivityHero extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;

    Button btnAllies;
    Button pick;
Button button_sborka;
    ImageView tallents;
    ImageView aganim;
    ImageView shard;
    View skill1;
    View skill2;
    View skill3;
    View skill4;

    Dialog dialogAganim;
    Dialog dialogShard;
    Dialog dialogTalletns;
    Dialog dialogSpell1;
    Dialog dialogSpell2;
    Dialog dialogSpell3;
    Dialog dialogSpell4;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hero);
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        btnAllies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAllies);
        btnAllies.setOnClickListener(this);

       pick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_pick);
        pick.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_sborka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sborka);
        button_sborka.setOnClickListener(this);

        tallents = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tallents);
       tallents.setOnClickListener(this);

        aganim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aganim_button);
        aganim.setOnClickListener(this);

        shard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shard);
        shard.setOnClickListener(this);

        skill1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewSkill1);
        skill1.setOnClickListener(this);

        skill2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewSkill2);
        skill2.setOnClickListener(this);

        skill3 = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewSkill3);
        skill3.setOnClickListener(this);

        skill4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewSkill4);
        skill4.setOnClickListener(this);

        dialogAganim = new Dialog(this);
        dialogShard = new Dialog(this);
        dialogTalletns = new Dialog(this);
        dialogSpell1 = new Dialog(this);
        dialogSpell2 = new Dialog(this);
        dialogSpell3 = new Dialog(this);
        dialogSpell4 = new Dialog(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAgillity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAllies:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAllies.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_pick:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityContrPick.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_sborka:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySborka.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_sborka:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySborka.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.aganim_button:

               aganim();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.shard:

                shard();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.shard:

                shard();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tallents:

                talletns();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.viewSkill1:

                dialogSpell1();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.viewSkill2:

                dialogSpell2();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.viewSkill3:

                dialogSpell3();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.viewSkill4:

                dialogSpell4();
                // TODO Call second activity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    private void aganim (){
 dialogAganim.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_aganim);
 dialogAganim.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogAganim.show();

    }
    private void shard (){
        dialogShard.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_shard);
        dialogShard.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogShard.show();


    }
    private void talletns (){
        dialogTalletns.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_talents);
        dialogTalletns.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogTalletns.show();


    }
    private void dialogSpell1 (){
        dialogSpell1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_ability1);
        dialogSpell1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogSpell1.show();


    }
    private void dialogSpell2 (){
        dialogSpell2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_ability2);
        dialogSpell2.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogSpell2.show();


    }
    private void dialogSpell3(){
        dialogSpell3.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_ability3);
        dialogSpell3.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogSpell3.show();


    }
    private void dialogSpell4 (){
        dialogSpell4.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_ability4);
        dialogSpell4.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogSpell4.show();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в свое время создавал массив классов со всеми героями:

```
public static Heroes[] heroesList = {
        new Heroes("Abaddon", R.drawable.pic_hero_abaddon, 1, "100200020",
                "22 +2.6", "23 +1.5", "18 +2.0",
                "50-60", "1.7", "150", null,
                "2.8", "25%",
                325, "0.6", "1800/800",
                R.array.talents_abaddon, HeroesAbilities.abaddon_abilities,
                HeroesAghanims.abaddon_aghanims, 1, 1, 102,
                "640 +3.2", "291 +1.2"),
        //...
};
```

В каждого героя передавал соответствующий массив класса способностей:

```
public static HeroesAbilities[] abaddon_abilities = {
        new HeroesAbilities("Mist Coil", R.drawable.pic_ability_abaddon_mist_coil,
                "5.5", "50",
                R.string.abaddon_mist_coil_description_1, R.string.abaddon_mist_coil_description_2,
                new Integer[]{R.string.ABILITY_UNIT_TARGET, R.string.AFFECTS_UNITS, R.string.DAMAGE_TYPE_MAGICAL, R.string.PIERCES_SPELL_IMMUNITY_1, 0},
                R.array.abaddon_mist_coil, new String[]{"50%", "110/160/210/260", "575"}),
        //...
};
```

И передавал в активити с героем лишь его номер, а дальше уже из массива из первого пункта доставалось и расставлялось все, что нужно.

```
private void pasteHeroData(){
    Heroes currentHero = Heroes.heroesList[heroNumber];
    //Name
    TextView heroName = findViewById(R.id.heroName);
    heroName.setText(currentHero.name);
    //Image
    ImageView heroImage = findViewById(R.id.heroImage);
    heroImage.setImageResource(currentHero.imageId);
    //HP & Mana
    TextView hp = findViewById(R.id.hp), mana = findViewById(R.id.mana);
    hp.setText(currentHero.hp);
    mana.setText(currentHero.mana);
    //Attributes
    TextView strength = findViewById(R.id.strength), agility = findViewById(R.id.agility),
            intelligence = findViewById(R.id.intelligence);
    strength.setText(currentHero.strength);
    agility.setText(currentHero.agility);
    intelligence.setText(currentHero.intelligence);
    //...
}
```

Если я правильно понял, то тебя беспокоит создание более сотни активити для каждого героя. Так вот это не нужно, мне на всех хватило всего одной.

P.S: В код можешь не вдумываться – он тут как идея. Думаю создать классы на данном этапе трудности не составит.

```
public Heroes(String name, int imageID, int primary_attribute_number, String roles,
              String strength, String agility, String intelligence,
              String base_damage, String attack_speed, String attack_range, String projectile_speed,
              String armor, String magic_resistance,
              int move_speed, String turn_rate, String vision_range,
              int talents_array, HeroesAbilities[] abilities_list, HeroesAghanims[] aghanims_list,
              int attack_type, int complexity, int add_number,
              String hp, String mana) {
    this.name = name;
    this.imageId = imageID;
    this.primary_attribute_number = primary_attribute_number;
    this.roles = roles;
    this.strength = strength;
    this.agility = agility;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
    this.base_damage = base_damage;
    this.attack_speed = attack_speed;
    this.attack_range = attack_range;
    this.projectile_speed = projectile_speed;
    this.armor = armor;
    this.magic_resistance = magic_resistance;
    this.move_speed = move_speed;
    this.turn_rate = turn_rate;
    this.vision_range = vision_range;
    this.talents_array = talents_array;
    this.abilities_list = abilities_list;
    this.aghanims_list = aghanims_list;
    this.attack_type = attack_type;
    this.complexity = complexity;
    this.add_number = add_number;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.mana = mana;
}
```

Comment: То что нужно! Реализация стала понятна... я примерно так и представлял, что через массив, но вот пока некоторые моменты не ясно как сделать... есть ли у вас возможность сбросить больше когда? буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Или может подскажите от какой концепции отталкиваться , мб есть какие то готовые примеры? Не совсем понимаю полную реализацию :(

Comment: Ну я же не буду за тебя писать все приложение или переписывать всех героев. Все что тебе нужно – научиться создавать классы и создать с ними массивы. Список героев, который, как я догадываюсь, у тебя состоит из множества ImageView, которые ты добавлял вручную, тебе нужно заменить на RecyclerView. А далее ты просто из этого RecyclerView открываешь активити с героем, куда передается его номер из этого же RecyclerView. Открыв активити, у тебя начинается 3 пункт моего ответа, где Heroes – класс героя, а heroesList – массив этого класса со всеми героями. Классы и RecyclerView – это 2 простые темы.

Comment: К комментарию выше – RecyclerView строить нужно по тому же массиву с классами героя, чтобы позиция в Recycler'е совпадала с его позицией в массиве, но, надеюсь, это было очевидно. Свой вид класса героя добавил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение! этого достаточно)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам столько imageBotton ? Используйте RecyclerView и класс PoJo (module) ! Это не так уж сложно (°_°)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]